# Visualizing a social network on a (geographical) map

Tags: api, maps, visualization, social-networking, neo4j

I'd like to show a social network on a map, but I have no experience with mapping APIs.

I think its fairly straightforward to plot a long/lat on, say, Google Maps.
But then if that point needs to have contacts fanning out from it, with lines indicating the network, this could be harder.

Can anyone recommend a library/API that can do this already?
I specifically need one that can render *lots* of lines and points (edges and nodes) very nicely, and can zoom in on them.

I'm very competent in Python, Django and JavaScript so could make a new open-source library to do this, but thought I should check first if one already exists!
If not, I'm thinking of creating a mashup perhaps between neo4j and d3's Force-directed graph.

Answer (score 0):

So,
in Javascript a very competent library is OpenLayers, see for instance the GeoJSON example, http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/geojson.html which should not be hard to implement. There are others, liek GoogleMaps etc.

I like your alias. Smells XKCD.